# python how to store a list in a file and get it back

Tags: python, list, file, save

I have a list with a lot of things in.
At the end of my script I would like to store it in a file. 
And when I start another script another day, I would like to extract my list from my file and then use it.
I don't know if it's the best way to do this.

Here is what i would like to do in "code" for those who didn't understand

```
#script1
l = ('hey', 'ho', 'hello', 'world')
#save list into myfile


#script2
l = getmylistfrommyfile()
print(l)
>>>('hey', 'ho', 'hello', 'world')
#I can now use my list !
```

Comment: do you know about `pickle`?

Comment: For God's sake! That is a tuple, not a list. And don't name your variables as list as they shadow the builtin

Comment: don't use list as a variable name, it is a built-in type

Comment: or JSON, YAML, CSV...

Comment: @JulienSpronck no I don't. Should i use iT? list was for the example I don't use it in my code sorry

Comment: yes you should (or some other module but pickle is straightforward) ... just look it up

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are looking for the best and most pythonic way of doing this then [Pickling](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html) is a better idea. It is as simple as :

```
#Save a dictionary into a pickle file.
import pickle

favorite_color = { "lion": "yellow", "kitty": "red" }

pickle.dump( favorite_color, open( "save.p", "wb" ) )



# Load the dictionary back from the pickle file.

favorite_color = pickle.load( open( "save.p", "rb" ) )
```

Comment: nice thanks can you give me an example too to get favorite color back?